# Which icons in the icons directiory does Apache use when auto-generating indexes?

Tags: apache, icons

Apache's [`mod_autoindex` module](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html) can generate an index of files if there's no user-created `index.html file`. With the [`FancyIndexing` option](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexoptions.fancyindexing) turned on, Apache also adds an icon next to the file based on its filename.

In the `/usr/share/apache2/icons` directory that these icons come from, there's 74 different icons (I'm only counting gifs of the right size).

Those icons are:

```
a.gif
alert.black.gif
alert.red.gif
back.gif
ball.gray.gif
ball.red.gif
binary.gif
binhex.gif
blank.gif
bomb.gif
box1.gif
box2.gif
broken.gif
burst.gif
c.gif
comp.blue.gif
comp.gray.gif
compressed.gif
continued.gif
dir.gif
diskimg.gif
down.gif
dvi.gif
f.gif
folder.gif
folder.open.gif
folder.sec.gif
forward.gif
generic.gif
generic.red.gif
generic.sec.gif
hand.right.gif
hand.up.gif
image1.gif
image2.gif
image3.gif
index.gif
layout.gif
left.gif
link.gif
movie.gif
p.gif
patch.gif
pdf.gif
pie0.gif
pie1.gif
pie2.gif
pie3.gif
pie4.gif
pie5.gif
pie6.gif
pie7.gif
pie8.gif
portal.gif
ps.gif
quill.gif
right.gif
screw1.gif
screw2.gif
script.gif
sound1.gif
sound2.gif
sphere1.gif
sphere2.gif
tar.gif
tex.gif
text.gif
transfer.gif
unknown.gif
up.gif
uu.gif
uuencoded.gif
world1.gif
world2.gif
```

I found [and old post](https://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20021107063219391) that claims "Out of all of them it only uses 25".

Is this true? Which of the icons are actually used in the auto index?

I'd like to create my own set of icons, so I want to know which ones I should actually create and which ones aren't used.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/557852/what-would-cause-apache-to-display-a-bomb-icon-for-a-specific-directory/557854#557854?newreg=18fdbfd1906747e7b74dad532bd36cfe)!

The default configuration for mod_autoindex is defined in a file called `extra/httpd-autoindex.conf`.

```
#
# AddIcon* directives tell the server which icon to show for different
# files or filename extensions.  These are only displayed for
# FancyIndexed directories.
#
AddIconByEncoding (CMP,/icons/compressed.gif) x-compress x-gzip

AddIconByType (TXT,/icons/text.gif) text/*
AddIconByType (IMG,/icons/image2.gif) image/*
AddIconByType (SND,/icons/sound2.gif) audio/*
AddIconByType (VID,/icons/movie.gif) video/*

AddIcon /icons/binary.gif .bin .exe
AddIcon /icons/binhex.gif .hqx
AddIcon /icons/tar.gif .tar
AddIcon /icons/world2.gif .wrl .wrl.gz .vrml .vrm .iv
AddIcon /icons/compressed.gif .Z .z .tgz .gz .zip
AddIcon /icons/a.gif .ps .ai .eps
AddIcon /icons/layout.gif .html .shtml .htm .pdf
AddIcon /icons/text.gif .txt
AddIcon /icons/c.gif .c
AddIcon /icons/p.gif .pl .py
AddIcon /icons/f.gif .for
AddIcon /icons/dvi.gif .dvi
AddIcon /icons/uuencoded.gif .uu
AddIcon /icons/script.gif .conf .sh .shar .csh .ksh .tcl
AddIcon /icons/tex.gif .tex
AddIcon /icons/bomb.gif core

AddIcon /icons/back.gif ..
AddIcon /icons/hand.right.gif README
AddIcon /icons/folder.gif ^^DIRECTORY^^
AddIcon /icons/blank.gif ^^BLANKICON^^

#
# DefaultIcon is which icon to show for files which do not have an icon
# explicitly set.
#
DefaultIcon /icons/unknown.gif
```

Here's the whole file for reference: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf.in

So the answer is that by default, these 25 icons are used in the index:

- compressed.gif
- text.gif
- image2.gif
- sound2.gif
- movie.gif
- binary.gif
- binhex.gif
- tar.gif
- world2.gif
- a.gif
- layout.gif
- text.gif
- c.gif
- p.gif
- f.gif
- dvi.gif
- uuencoded.gif
- script.gif
- tex.gif
- bomb.gif
- back.gif
- hand.right.gif
- folder.gif
- blank.gif
- unknown.gif

Of course, more can be added with the [AddIcon Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html#addicon)